# Excel AutoComplete and AutoFill keyboard shortcut

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Does any one have a keyboard shortcut for excel that performs **AutoFill** and **AutoComplete** at the same time, as an alternative to the mouse *i.e* : **selection** ( 1 2 3 ) **+ doubleclick** (bottom right hand side):

```
+--- +-------+
|Rank|  A    |
+--- +-------+
| 1  | a     |
| 2  | b     |
| 3  | c     |
|    | d     |
|    | e     |
|    | f     |
|    | g     |
+--- +-------+
```

I know a keyboard alternative : **ALT+E+ENTER+I+S+F+ENTER** but this does not do the whole job (auto complete as the mouse-double-click).

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/298276/excel-keyboard-shortcut-to-copy-fill-down-for-all-cells-with-non-blank-adjacent

Answer (score 2):

In order, press and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>, to bring up the Series input. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the defaults.

By Default, Linear option is selected, that's for numeric values!
For auto-filling months or days, select Autofill option and then ENTER.

Comment: What I would like to acheive is to find a shortcut to autofill without having to select the range to fill , just as a mouse double click on a cell containing formula. Alt + E+I+S doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use Ctlr+Down/Right key to select the cells you want to fill and press Ctrl+D (to fill down) or Ctrl+R (to fill right). Read more of this [Autofill Techniqes here](https://softwareaccountant.com/excel-auto-fill/).

Comment: This only works in a cell immediately below or to the right of a filled cell. It doesn't work to fill a whole column or row.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell that you want to copy contains a formula, then my solution is to make this cell active, and select the region where I want to copy the formula to, using Shift + Down Arrow or Ctrl + Shift + End, or sg like this. So the white cell of the selected area will be the cell I want to copy. Then pressing F2, and then Ctrl + Enter will make the copy.

If you want to autocomplete the area with numbers, first select the area, and then press Alt, and then the letters to reach Autocomplete, and in there the Autocomplete Series (or sg like this, my Office is Hungarian). The default settings in the window should be good, so you only need to press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Selection + Double click on the bottom right hand, invokes the default values in the Fill Series dialog (Menu: Home -> Fill -> Series + Enter).

You can easily invoke the above without any mouse interaction using this shortcut:<kbd>Alt + H + F + I + S + Enter</kbd>